# Exporting SQL Database to phpMyAdmin 5.1.65

Tags: sql, import, phpmyadmin, export

I'm currently trying to follow the instructions off of [this website](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/mysql_export.htm) to export a SQL database to one stored on a different server.

The problem that's occurring is I'm trying to export a SQL database coming from phpMyAdmin 2.7.0 into the phpMyAdmin 5.1.65. The error message I keep getting whenever I try and import it is:

> You attempted to load file with unsupported compression (application/zip). Either support for it is not implemented or disabled by your configuration.

Is it that the old database isn't compatible with the new version of phpMyAdmin?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: export a pure sql fike instead a zipped file

Comment: @silly I tried to export a pure sql file and then import it into the system. That didn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

phpMyAdmin is not a database server.  It is simply a tool to access MySQL database servers with a GUI.  There are any number of reasons the export/import could be going wrong including:

- Use of different versions of MySQL
- MySQL user configuration differences between servers
- Problems with the way phpMyAdmin creates export scripts on the older version that provides incompatibility with MySQL on newer server.

I would suggest you look closely at the error messages you are getting as a starting point in trying to figure out the problem.

Maybe take phpMyAdmin out of the equation altogether and do your DB dump/import via MySQL command line tools (mysql and mysqldump) so that you can get immediate feedback for where there may be issues.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I figured out that I needed to do the basic steps of:
1) creating the database name
2) importing that database into the newly created name
3) create a user for the newly created database, so;
4) I go into the database.php file to edit the database linkage information

Hopefully this helps someone else with the same issues.